# How can I get the checked radio button value from a previous page in js/

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two js files and two html forms. In the first form there are two radio buttons, upon selection of a radio button the user clicks on continue button to move to the next page (this is the second form). I need to disable a particular section of the second form based on the radio button selected in the first form.

Is it possible to get the value of checked radio button from the first form onto the second form in js?

Comment: How are you posting your form? GET or POST? You should include your code here. Do you have a backend language? You can often reference the `form` object with that.

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods you can do this

**Cookies**

You can make a session cookie and add the radio button choice to it, then parse it on the next page!

As requested, with jQuery:

On page 1:
`` $.cookie("options", `form1_radio={option}`) ``

On page 2:
`alert($.cookie("options"))`

**Parameters**

You can pass the option in a URL parameter to the next page!

Comment: Do you have any example on how cookies option can be done in jQuery

Comment: Check my answer!

Comment: Thanks Jay. I'm trying to use the syntax that you've mentioned but I'm just getting cookies not defined. I've also tried using Cookies.set() and Cookies.get() syntax but its the same case. The jQuery version I'm using is 1.11.1. Any idea what can be done?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way, but you can use `url parameters`.

```
location.href = 'https://www.example.com/?radioButton=2'
```

And on the other side,

```
let previousRadioButton = /(?<=radioButton=)\d+/.exec(location.href)[0]
```